# How to find starting velocity for a body thrown by an angle when known distance it must pass?

Tags: physics

From course of mechanic, we know, that to find distance, passed by a body thrown by an angle, we need to use that formula:

Sy(t) = V0 * sin(angle) * t - (g*t*t) / 2;
Sx(t) = V0 * cos(angle) * t;

My question is, how do we find the right starting velocity, if we know the distance body must pass (Sx and Sy) and angle (let's say, it's 45 degrees)?

I tried to derive formula, but it seems to be wrong:

V0 = ( Sy(t) + (g * t * t) / 2 ) / sin(angle_in_rads);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your starting velocity is a vector, not a scalar (to be pedantic, `V0` is actually the *speed*, i.e. the magnitude of the velocity).

If `v0x= v0*cos(a)` and `v0y= v0*sin(a)`, then your analytical solution for the positions is correct:
`sx(t) = v0*cos(a)*t` and `sy(t) = v0*sin(a)*t - g*t^2/2`.

Your question is ambiguous, but assuming you want to find the launch speed and angle that allows you to reach a maximum height (`sy_max`) and a maximum range (`sx_max`), then this is how to approach it:

- the maximum height is attained when the instantaneous  velocity attains a null vertical component. Since `vy = v0*sin(a) - g*t` then `t_sy_max = v0*sin(a)/g`. Since you know `sy_max = sy(t_sy_max)`, you have found one equation.
- the maximum range is attained when `sy` becomes zero (and `t > 0`, naturally). So you start with the equation `0 = v0*sin(a)*t_max - g*t_max^2/2` from where you find tour `t_max = 2*v0*sin(a)/g`. Due to the symmetry of the parabola, you can confirm that `t_max = 2*t_sy_max`. You end up with the second equation, mainly `sx_max = sx(t_max)`.
- Both equations that you have written for the known `(sx_max, sy_max)` input pair are assembled into system of equations that is nonlinear (trigonometric in this case). You should be able to work out the values of `v0` and `a` from it.

Comment: @Your starting velocity is a vector, not a scalar  - that's right, I derived x and y components of a velocity vector by multiplying scalar speed onto sin and cos, respectively.

Comment: I've made a simple python program which should test my calculations, can you please look at it and say where I made a mistake? http://pastebin.com/nSMdAUDp

Comment: Hi, I've found my mistake and made a correction, now everything works as expected, thank you. Here's the right program in case someone will need it: http://pastebin.com/gDfkL2v0